# Is there a way for a Eclipse compiler to show address fields from variables as an integer value?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address

I'm currently doing projects on pointer variables in general and I'm using a virtual machine to mimic linux from my 64 bit OS. ***Keep in mind, this is C++.*** One thing I'm currently struggling with are using hexadecimal values. Rather than using that as a reference to where certain values are located, I want the output to simply show up as an integer. I tried type casting with int() but this isn't working. Is there a way to work around this for Linux Ubuntu on virtual machines using Eclipse compilers to show those address fields at integers?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:!!!!

```
int x = 0;
int * p = &x;
std::cout << p << std::endl;
std::cout << &x << std::endl;
return 0;
```

libraries that were used include iostream and nothing else.

Comment: Please, be more specific. Do you want to see a value in the debugger window or somewhere else?

Comment: Ripi2 1. I do want to see the output from a console.

Comment: `printf(...)` or `cout` is not enough?

Comment: No. Each time I use std::cout it just defaults to hexadecimals.

Comment: Please show your code, its not really clear what the problem is, because `cout` (possibly with a iomanipulator) should do what you want out of the box

Comment: Check the edits everyone. Thanks by the way, I really do appreciate the help right now.

Comment: well not really out of the box, but the dupe has the solution

Comment: Just for clarification sake... 

There are no libraries inside the "box" of C++ by default that can just output this directly? Nothing from iomanip? This seems like initializing functions to get that integer value I would want.

Comment: btw Eclipse is not actually a compiler. It is a glorified text editor.

Comment: You say you tried casting to `int`? I don't see that anywhere in your code. But why do you want to? What's wrong with using the hexadecimal value?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on a 64 bit computer, the addresses will be 64 bits long, while an `int` is typically only 32 bits. Therefore a cast to an `int` will lose precision, which is not permitted. `long long` on the other hand is an integer type that holds 64 bits, so casting to that would call an overload of `operator<<` that by default prints in decimal.